# qt изменение объектов формы из отдельного потока приводит к ошибке

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gui, c++17

Есть событие:

```
void MainWindow::OnShow(){
    // Start OnShow actions
    ui->LoadingBox->setVisible(true);
    std::thread dThread(OnShow_threaded, ui, &(this->settingsMap));
    dThread.join();
}
```

Есть функция *OnShow_threaded*:

```
void OnShow_threaded(Ui::MainWindow *ui, std::unordered_map<QString,QString> *settingsMap){

    // Connect to server
    bool hasInternet = true;
   
    // If app doesn't have Internet access -> show offline mode
    if (!hasInternet) {
        ui->SettingsLabel->setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Программа вылетает при компиляции статической сборки с ошибкой:

> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to
> objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 0x0x36c56540.
> Receiver 'WarningMsg' (of type 'QGroupBox') was created in thread
> 0x0x341c2fa0", file kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 558

На строке: `ui->SettingsLabel->setVisible(true);`

При этом при динамической линковке данной ошибки нет.
Не подскажите, как устранить подобную ошибку?

Полный проект можно посмотреть здесь: [GitHub](https://github.com/SlimRG/DWAKU2)

Comment: Сразу оговорюсь - я не стал переписывать весь код, но сократил его до места, где наблюдается ошибка. Поэтому не надо спрашивать - нафиг мне отдельный поток.

Comment: Самое первое - перестать ругаться. А во вторых - нельзя из не главного потока изменять UI, так устроено большинство ui фреймворков. Что делать? создать специальный сигнал, который посылать с потока главному окну, предварительно соединив его с помощью Qt::QueuedConnection или Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection (по потребностям). Если все правильно делать, то connect сам все правильно подключит

Comment: @KoVadim А можете написать, как это делается?

Comment: вот пример можно посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545961/modify-qt-gui-from-background-worker-thread - если сигнал слоты умеете, то проблем никаких нет. Главное, это помнить, что при Qt::QueuedConnection Ваш сигнал "копируется" в очередь другого потока. И если Вы передаете слишком много сигналов, будет весело. Если передать ссылку на локальную переменную или какой то указатель - тоже. Поэтому, лучше сделать копию или умные указатели

Comment: @KoVadim я только учусь - как сделать слот - умею. А вот что касается привязки сигналов к слотам - неочень. Поэтому и попросил показать) Буду очень признателен, если покажите концепцию - дальше методом научного тыка, думаю, разбирусь

Comment: просто connect, как обычно.

Comment: @KoVadim эм... не совсем понимаю, как это сделать. Можете показать. Очень вас прошу.

Comment: я привел ссылку на пример. Нужно сделать ровно 3 вещи - добавить окну новый слот, который выведет сообщение, добавить новый сигнал в поток и не забыть о его emit  в нужный момент и все это соединить через connect в том месте, где создается поток. Не было бы ругательств, был бы код.

Comment: @KoVadim я не ругался. Просто я уже неделю пытаюсь создать этот вопрос и именно с этим ответом мне минусят и закрывают его. Вы - первый кто дал хоть какую-то инфу, кроме отказа от потоков и использования главного... За это огромное вам спасибо. Информацию сейчас изучаю.... Не подскажите - что такое emit

Comment: @KoVadim не подскажите, что должно быть внутри команды connect для моего случая?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Лучшие ответы - здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66063164/how-can-i-change-gui-from-stdthread
P.S. Да, на английском - кто не знает его, воспользуйтесь translate.yandex.ru для сайтов

Comment: если бы translate.yandex.ru хотя бы работал...

Comment: @KoVadim - он работает.... возможно у вас проблемы с интернет подключением....

Comment: если я сюда пишу, то видимо нет проблем с "интернет подключением":)

Comment: @KoVadim Как бы банально это не звучало - у меня все открывается.